# How to reload page on each itteration of waiter

Tags: java, selenium, async-await, webdriver, awaitility

I want to reload the page on each iteration of **`Awaitility.await()`** to check if the text of the element is changed.

My code:

```
Awaitility.await()
        .pollInterval(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .atMost(30, SECONDS)
        .until(() -> driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getText(), equalTo(EXPECTED_TEXT));
}
```

And I want to reload page on each **`.pollInterval`**, every 5 sec, with:

```
driver.navigate().refresh()
```

How can I achieve this?
Or suggest a better solution with java.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop and `Thread.sleep(...)` would be there easiest way:

```
String xpath = "//*[contains(., '" + EXPECTED_TEXT +"')]";
WebElement element = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    try {
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        break;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

if (element != null) {
    // Found it!
}
```

Six tries multiplied by 5 seconds will give you an approximate maximum of 30 seconds.